# asp.net mvc3 RouteToAction() not taking me anywhere

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, routes

I'm using jquerymobile and asp.net MVC3 razor. I'm somewhat new to this, but figuring things out, I have a very basic route table, with just the ignore route for `.axd` resources and a default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default",
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have an action link that works in an .ascx page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account", null, new { @class = "ui-btn-right" })
```

Now, when I get to the LogOn page, and I complete the account verification, I need to send them to the home page, `/Home/Home` which works if I type it in the address bar, but I can't seem to get my redirect working in the account controller: `return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am struggling with exact problem, have u found solution, pls answer ur question. I am using same technologies which u r using.

Comment: @Sutikshan Dubey - No, I haven't, I'll throw a bounty on it and see if anyone can help out :)

Comment: First, I don't know if this will help with your problem, so I'll pose it as a comment instead of an answer, but your default route is setup a little weird.

id = "", UrlParameter.Optional
should be:
id = UrlParameter.Optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you're posting your form from /Account/LogOn via ajax.  That means that when you `return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");`, the page wouldn't change.  So you just need to not use ajax on the form submit.  If my guess is wrong, please post more code so we can get an idea of what the problem is.

It appears from the documentation that jQuery mobile handles form posts via ajax automatically.  To prevent this, add the `data-ajax="false"` attribute to the form element.  Documentation here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html

Comment: I'm using JqueryMobile, so yeah, I'm pretty certain its doing an ajax post. Is there a good way to fix this problem, using JqueryMobile?

Comment: As a side note, I'm not familiar with jQuery mobile so it may be that you want to post via ajax and then just replace your page with what's passed back to your success function.

Comment: Yeah, that's what they do, is post via ajax and then replace the page. If I want to continue down this route, not disabling ajax, is there a good method to use instead of "RedirectToAction()"?

Comment: no, for your server it shouldn't matter what your client is doing.  However, in a fully ajax site, I would suggest using only return PartialView() from all your actions.  You can then dispatch the HTML returned from the server this way to the appropriate part of the page (refresh only what's necessary seems to be the intent of this ajax as a default paradigm).

Comment: But what if the user requests that page from the get-go, rather than just from an Ajax request? won't they not get a full page?

Comment: Right, of course, sorry.  You can find out if it's an ajax request with `Request.IsAjaxRequest` from any controller action.  You can then use that to render a partial or full view.  There are many other ways to handle this.  Action filters, areas, etc.  But that may be better left as another question.

Answer (score 1):

Given what's written in [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/forms/forms-sample.html), could you put your code into a form element and setting its action property to /Account/LogOn ? In order to do that, you may have to convert your ActionLink into a  button.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for ajax request in controller:

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
  //send json object and do navigate in client
  return Json(new {IsLogged = true});
}
else
{ 
  //send redirect html code to browser
  return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
}
```

and in client side, check for json result if you post form by jQuery ajax.
I'm not use jquerymobile so I don't know how it work in client side.

Comment: But I want that ajax request to return the page, because the client side of jQueryMobile fetches new pages via ajax.